# why remote debug enter breakpoint invalid

Tags: java, jvm, remote-debugging

I try remote debug application, the first few times I could enter the breakpoint, but later attempts will only block the request, not enter the breakpoint

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and then elaborate. With just the information you've provided it's hard to tell what's going on and all we can do is guess. My guess would be that you've updated your application and now the breakpoints don't match anymore.

Comment: explain your question.it can have several reasons.if you change your code you should stop and start java application then start remote debugging again

Comment: I have not changed my code, this happens many times, as long as the restart can be resolved, but I want to know why